# Initiate new center on load SVG pan zoom

Tags: svgpanzoom

To change the position of an SVG with SvgPanZoom one has to use

```
panZoomInstance.pan({x: *value*, y: *value*});
```

But this causes SvgPanZoom to move the SVG initially from center to the new position, as it will first place the SVG in the middle of the viewport by default.

Is there a way to force a different center point of the SVG onload before SvgPanZoom will place the SVG?

Best, hirschferkel

Answer (score 0):

svg-pan-zoom has 3 options that you can disable:

```
, fit: true
, contain: false
, center: true
```

Comment: Yes I know, but this will cause a jumping SVG onload with .pan option, as I wrote... Is it possible to insert some Javascriptcode somewhere in svgpanzoom.js to edit the center point so svgpanzoom will initially load a different center for the svg? even with `, fit: false, contain: false, center: false` >> svgpanzoom will center the svg onload.

Comment: O.k. it's just because the SVG gets loaded first and than svg-pan-zoom gets initalized. So the solution ist to hide the svg as long as svg-pan-zoom is initialized and than show the svg after it has been panned by svg-pan-zoom (within the onload function)